# Using and Stream

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I  call method in Soap extension which decrypt and verify sing Soap message.
I have this classes:

I have class, which decrypt and verify sign Soap message, which return stream back in Soap extension class :

Method DecryptAndVerifySingXml and GetGuid use stream from class soap extension.

```
public class CryptUtility
{
    public virtual Stream DecryptAndVerifySingXml(Stream inputStream)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(inputStream))
        {
            doc.Load(reader);
        }


        using (MemoryStream retStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            retStream.Position = 0;
            doc.Save(retStream);
        }

        //.....crypt and verify sing

        if (signedXml.CheckSignature(Key) == false)
        {
            throw new SecurityException("error");
        }

        else
        {
            using (MemoryStream retStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                doc.Save(retStream);
                return retStream;
            }
        }
    }

    //get value from Soap header
    public string GetGuid(MemoryStream inputStream)
    {
        inputStream.Position = 0;

        string soapBodyString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inputStream.ToArray());

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(soapBodyString);

        if (doc.GetElementsByTagName("Ticket").Item(0).InnerText == "")
        {
            throw new SecurityException("Neplatny uzivatel");
        }
        else
        {
            return doc.GetElementsByTagName("Ticket").Item(0).InnerText;
        }

    }
}
```

I use class CryptUtility in Soap extension class:

```
public class SoapMsg : SoapExtension
    {

        private CryptUtility cryptUtil = null;
        string GUID;

        //...
        public override void Initialize(object initializer)
        {
            SoapMsgAttribute attribute =
              initializer as SoapMsgAttribute;
            soapElement = attribute.SoapElementArray;

            //create instance
            cryptUtil = new CryptUtility();
        }

        //copy stream method
        private void CopyStream(Stream from, Stream to)
        {
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(from);
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(to);
            writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            writer.Flush(); 
        }

        private void DecryptMessage()
        {
            using (MemoryStream copyOldStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                CopyStream(oldStream, copyOldStream);

                copyOldStream.Position = 0;
                using (Stream retStream = cryptUtil.DecryptAndVerifySingXml(copyOldStream)
                {
                    retStream.Position = 0; //  < == in this place is bug   !!! line 183.
                    newStream.Position = 0;
                    CopyStream(retStream, newStream);
                    newStream.Position = 0;
                }
            }
        }


         public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
        {
            switch (message.Stage)
            {
                case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
                    {
                    }
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            CopyStream(oldStream, tempStream);

                            tempStream.Position = 0;

                            GUID = cryptUtil.GetGuid(tempStream);

                            oldStream.Position = 0;

                            // call method, in which is bug
                            DecryptMessage();
                    }
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("error");
            }
        }


    }
 }
```

In ProcessMessage in BeforeDeserialize I call method DecryptMessage() in wich is bug. On client side soap extension finish with this error :

**System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
   at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()**

The error is in line
:
                    retStream.Position = 0; //  < == in this place is bug   !!! line 183.
in method DecryptMessage().

First I used google, but I don't find solution for this error. Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're disposing of the stream which you then return - so the caller won't be able to use it.

Get rid of the `using` statements for the streams you return. You're also not using the stream in the first block, and you can get rid of the "else". Here's the complete `DecryptVerifySignXml` method with these changes:

```
public virtual Stream DecryptAndVerifySignXml(Stream inputStream)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(inputStream))
    {
        doc.Load(reader);
    }

    //.....crypt and verify sing

    if (!signedXml.CheckSignature(Key))
    {
        throw new SecurityException("error");
    }

    MemoryStream retStream = new MemoryStream();
    doc.Save(retStream);
    retStream.Position = 0; // Rewind so it's ready to use
    return retStream;
}
```

(I'm not sure the name of the method is particularly valid, I have to say - that method isn't doing any decryption and it's not signing anything - it's just loading some XML and checking an existing signature. Anyway, that's by the by...)

Your `CopyStream` method is broken, however - it assumes the contents is UTF-8-encoded text. That may be true in some cases, but not all. You should use something like this instead:

```
static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `using` from your `retStream` declaration; so change this

```
using (MemoryStream retStream = new MemoryStream())
```

with this

```
MemoryStream retStream = new MemoryStream();
```

Comment: Right, once using-block is left (either through fall-through or jumping/crashing out of it), the object will be destroyed (and the Stream closed) asap. So if you want to keep it outside the block, do not use "using"!

Comment: @Marcel, ty; I already had a lot problems returning "used variables", so now I understand I must take care returning them; btw, why .net dispose them, as still a reference to them? I'll open a question about this