# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file in C# asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, download, filestream

I am sending a file to client for download. File could be big (upto few GBs), so I am sending it in chunks. This is my code:

```
//code to get data in resp stream.
        using (Stream inputStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(TargetFile))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(TargetFile);
            }
            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(TargetFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[SegmentSize];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, SegmentSize)) > 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
                }
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;filename=targetFileName.pdf");
                return File(fs, "application/pdf");
            }
        }
```

When I click on the link to download it gives me above error. I tried with returning nothing and in that case it downloads the file but size of the file is zero. The error is in the last line.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584785/using-and-stream

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue attaching the uploaded file(s) to an email. Adding the below to the web.config worked:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="20000"  useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192"/>
</system.web>
```